# How do I use values as a column headers in a SQL Server Query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a view that outputs Name, Field, Value like so:

```
 Name | Field | Value  
------|-------|------
Item1 |  SKU  | 83841  
Item1 |  UOM  | EA  
Item1 |  QTY  | 47  
Item2 |  SKU  | 83458  
Item2 |  UOM  | PK  
Item2 |  QTY  | 88
```

And I want to get:

```
 Name |  SKU  | UOM | QTY  
------|-------|-----|----
Item1 | 83841 | EA  | 47
Item2 | 83458 | PK  | 88
```

I have tried Pivot, but if I aggregate Name, then I only get one value.  Here is my query:

```
SELECT SKU, UOM, QTY
FROM
(
    SELECT Field, Value
    FROM dbo.ProductExport
) d
PIVOT
(
    MAX(FieldValue)
    for Value in (SKU, UOM, QTY)
) piv;
```

I feel like it just might not be possible without a unique value, but I might just be missing something too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `FOR Field` because PIVOTed columns come from `Field`:

```
SELECT Name, SKU, UOM, QTY
FROM
(
    SELECT Name, Field, Value
    FROM dbo.ProductExport
) d
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Value)
    for Field in (SKU, UOM, QTY)
) piv;
```

Also Add `Name` to the subquery and replace `fieldvalue` by `value` which is the data you want in your table.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7aab/9) (thanks to Giannis Paraskevopoulos):

Comment: Prepared an SQLFiddle with your answer...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e7aab/9 Do not forget to change `@data` to what OP has as a table.

Comment: edit already done... thanks. I will add your fiddle to my answer (I hope it is ok with you).

Comment: Thanks! that was exactly it.

Comment: @JulienVavasseur Of course it is, and this is why i gave it. I was working on it as well, when i saw your answer, so a bit of mix and voila...